# When adding a "<" in front of a string it isn't displayed anymore

Tags: php, string

Whan happen when I add **'smaller than <** ' before the string ,because the string which has it in front was gone away [ didn't display when I **echo** them ] in my **PHP code。**

```
E.g:
$search = trim('wdisappear W');  //  all the words were disappeared when < in front
$search = explode(" ", $search); //
$sizeof_search = count($search);  //


for($i = 0; $i < $sizeof_search; $i++){
    $l = strlen($search[$i]);
    echo '<'.$search[$i].'<'.$l;
}
```

When I open the php file in **firefox** . **'wdisappear W'** doesn't appear! Why??

And how can I put the

> **<**

in front??

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `<` opens a html element. This will cause a part of the text to be invisible, because FF thinks it is meant as HTML markup. Escape it by outputting the `&lt;` html entity, or use `htmlspecialchars` function to escape the output for you.

Comment: if you view the page source you should see the correct output, it's just the html parser in the browser trying to make sense of it.

Answer (score 4):

By default PHP delivers content as `text/html` and in HTML `<` opens a tag. Thus your content is interpreted as an invalid tag and is not displayed. You should escape it using `&lt;`. There are other reserved characters, that need to be encoded. You can do all at once using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Alternatively you could deliver your content as `text/plain`, which does not require any escaping. (On the downside, you can't use HTML in there, obviously.)

Answer (score 3):

The character `<` has special meaning in HTML as the start of a tag. Call [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to convert the `<` to the HTML entity `&lt;` so that it displays correctly in the browser. You will probably also want to call this on the value of `$search[i]`, otherwise you could leave a [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerability in your application.

Try this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<' . $search[$i] . '<' . $l);
```

From the documentation:

> Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings. This function returns a string with some of these conversions made; the translations made are those most useful for everyday web programming.